# Projective space, showing open map to one point compactification of $\Bbb C$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, compactness, projective-space

Let $\Bbb P^1$ be complex projective space with the quotient topology from $\Bbb C^2-\{0\}$, where we identify $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if there exists $\lambda\in\Bbb C^\times$ such that $\lambda(a,b)=(c,d)$. Denote the equivalence class of $(a,b)$ by $[a:b]$.

Let $\Bbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ be the one point compactification of $\Bbb C$. I want to show that the map
$$\gamma:\Bbb{P}^1\to\Bbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$$
given by
$$\gamma([1:b/a])=b/a$$
$$\gamma([0:1])=\infty,$$
is open.

I have shown that whenever $U\subset U_0\subset\Bbb{P}^1$ doesn't contain $[0:1]$ that it is open. So I am only interested in $U$ open in $\Bbb{P}^1$ containing $[0:1]$.

I denote by $U_0=\{[a:b]\mid a\ne 0\}$.

So let $U$ be open in $\Bbb{P}^1$ such that $[0:1]\in U$. Then $U=(U\cap U_0)\cup \{[0:1]\}$, and thus $\gamma(U)=\gamma(U\cap U_0)\cup \gamma([0:1])=\gamma(U\cap U_0)\cup\{\infty\}$. Where previous calculations show $\gamma(U\cap U_0)$ is open in $\Bbb {C}$.

> This means that (from the definition of the topology of the one point compactification) all that is left is to show that $\gamma(U\cap U_0)^c$ is quasi-compact, but I can't seem to show this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that $\gamma(U)$ contains a neighborhood of $\infty$. Such a neighborhood can be of the form $\infty\cup \mathbb{C}-\bar B(0,r)$, where $\bar B(0,r)$ is the closed ball of radius $r$.

Since the topology of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is the quotient topology, $U$ contains a ball $p(B((0,1),s)$ where $p:\mathbb{C}^2-\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ is the quotient map. Let $z\in \mathbb{C}-\bar B(0,s)$, ${1\over{|z|}}<s$ implies that $({1\over z},1)\in B((0,1);s)$, this implies that $\mathbb{C}-\bar B(0,s)\subset\gamma(p(B(0,s))\subset\gamma(U)$.